# Delegating to Sister - strange behaviour

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual, multiple-inheritance

What would the following code print? I understand the output of the first 2 lines but the third line prints "Child" which I do not understand:

```
#include <iostream>

#define PRINT(a) std::cout << a << std::endl;

class Parent {
public:
    virtual void whoami() {
        PRINT("Parent");
    }
};

class Child : virtual public Parent {
public:
    void whoami() {
        PRINT("Child");
    }
};

class GrandChild : virtual public Parent, virtual public Child {//changing the order of inheritance does not change anything
};

int main() {
    Parent *parent = new Parent;
    Child *child = new Child;
    GrandChild *grandChild = new GrandChild;

    parent->whoami();//prints "Parent"
    child->whoami();//prints "Child"
    grandChild->whoami();//Prints "Child". Why so?
    return 0;
}
```

This is the output, with and without `virtual` in `Parent`'s `whoami` method. Can someone please explain the output?

```
Parent
Child
Child
```

Why doesn't the `virtual` keyword in `Parent`'s `whoami` method change anything?

Why changing the order of inheritance i.e. `virtual public Parent, virtual public Child` vs. `virtual public Child, virtual public Parent` does NOT change anything?

Comment: What do you mean by "the virtual keyword in Parent's whoami method doesn't change the output."? Did you try without that keyword and the output was the same?

Comment: Which outputs do you get for `Child *grandChild = new GrandChild;` and `Parent *grandChild = new GrandChild;`? What if you remove the virtual keyword there?

Comment: Yes @Yunnosch , removing the `virtual` keyword does not change the output.

Comment: It's not that `virtual` grants that member functions of base class overrides the one of child class. It's the opposite. ;-) The experiment recommended by @Yunnosch should demonstrate this.

Comment: @Scheff Had some mistakes there, fixed it. Hope it is correct now, editing in a 5 minute hurry is bad for correctness...

Comment: Please show the output for using a different new(GrandChild) on pointers to all of the three classes. That will enlighten you. Using pointers always with the corresponding new does not really demonstrate anything useful.

Comment: There are 2 `virtual` keywords here. The virtual function keyword is required, the virtual inheritance should be removed as long as you don't have a `diamond inheritance`. The virtual function **allows** the inherited class to overwrite a function . If it doesn't the parents function is called.

Comment: @Yunnosch yes. I am only asking about the `virtual` keyword in the `whoami` method :)

Comment: @Yunnosch virtual inheritance is required as `GrandChild` inherits from both `Parent` and `Child`

Comment: @AlanBirtles Yes. I changed my mind about editing, because of ... instinct. I would really appreciate an answer on that part of the question code. I am quite sure that it would be useful and I think the question as asked, with the shown code implicitly asks about it.... (In contrast to OPs answer to my comment question...)

Comment: @Yunnosch removing this usage of the `virtual` inheritance bit (i.e. `virtual public Parent, virtual public Child`) makes `whoami()` ambiguous in the line `grandChild->whoami();`

Comment: DanAl Yes, I just realised (was told). Sorry for those comments. Trying to make the most of this question currently by pointing out that still answerable part. To be clear, I now consider it an interesting side part of the question, which cannot easily be removed for focusing.

Comment: @Scheff Your answer still was great. I hope I did not spoil your fun....

Comment: DanAl To understand your problem better: If the three clasess had a linear inheritance i.e. parent->child->grandchild instead of the the parent<-grandchild->child(->parent) "Y" shape, would you still have the same problem? With that linear inheritance, the question could be focused on only the method keywords `virtual` and answers would be easier and possibly more to the point you are pondering, because the class "virtual"s would not be needed.

Comment: @Scheff You are right about moving target questions. Please accept that I did not consider my comments to invite for one - on the contrary. Even with asking about the class virtuals, your answer would still be a helpful part, impressively elaborating on the method virtual part. If you feel otherwise however, I would like to apologise.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the `virtual` inheritance which was even in your first question. Virtual inheritance is something I rarely need but strongly try to prevent. It makes everything much more complicated. Considering that even something innocent like `int a, b;` ... `int c = a - b;` bears Undefined Behavior (subtraction could overflow), C++ is IMHO complicated enough without this... ;-)